# Definite Integral $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{x\sin x}{(x^2+a^2)(x^2+b^2)}\,\mathrm{d}x$

Tags: definite-integrals

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{x\sin x}{(x^2+a^2)(x^2+b^2)}\,\mathrm{d}x$$

This is easy to evaluate with complex analysis but is there an elementary way (substitution, partial fractions, integration by parts)?

Comment: You could probably try partial fraction decomposition on $\frac{x}{\left(x^2 + a\right)\left(x^2 + b\right)}$, but this is still going to require the integral of $\frac{\sin(x)}{x^2 + a^2}$ which isn't going to be easy (two applications of integration by parts may yield a result, but I doubt it).

Comment: WLOG if $a^2<b^2$ then you can write the numerator as $\displaystyle\frac{1}{b^2-a^2}(x^2+b^2-x^2-a^2)(xsin(x))$ and then break up accordingly. Note sure if this helps.

Comment: @JosephZambrano You should be able to assume $a^2 < b^2$ unless $a^2 = b^2$ (but then that's a special integral, right?).

Comment: It seems to me that you would have to write it in terms of the imaginary numbers which makes this _very_ tedious (and not even necessarily possible) to integrate.

Comment: When Wolfram cannot take the integral, it's likely that a closed form [integral](http://integrals.wolfram.com/index.jsp?expr=x*sin%28x%29+%2F+%28%28x%5E2+%2B+a%5E2%29+*+%28x%5E2+%2B+b%5E2%29%29&random=false) (i.e. using "elementary" methods) is not possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note
$$\int_0^\infty e^{-xt}\cos(at)dt=\frac{x}{x^2+a^2}$$
and hence
$$\int_0^\infty e^{-xt}(\cos(at)-\cos(bt))dt=-\frac1{a^2-b^2}\frac{x}{(x^2+a^2)(x^2+b^2)}.$$
Thus
\begin{eqnarray}
\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{x\sin x}{(x^2+a^2)(x^2+b^2)}dx&=&2\int_{0}^\infty \frac{x\sin x}{(x^2+a^2)(x^2+b^2)}dx\\
&=&-\frac2{a^2-b^2}\int_{0}^\infty\left(\int_{0}^\infty e^{-xt}(\cos(at)-\cos(bt))dt\right)\sin xdx\\
&=&-\frac1{a^2-b^2}\int_{0}^\infty(\cos(at)-\cos(bt))\left(\int_{0}^\infty e^{-xt}\sin x dx\right)dt\\
&=&-\frac2{a^2-b^2}\int_{0}^\infty\frac{\cos(at)-\cos(bt)}{t^2+1}dt\\
&=&-\frac2{a^2-b^2}\left(\frac{\pi}{2e^a}-\frac{\pi}{2e^b}\right)\\
&=&-\frac1{a^2-b^2}\left(\frac{\pi}{e^a}-\frac{\pi}{e^b}\right).
\end{eqnarray}
Here we used the following result
$$ \int_0^\infty\frac{\cos(a t)}{t^2+1}dt=\frac{\pi}{2e^a}. $$

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** First, prove that $I_n(t)=\displaystyle\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{\cos(tx)}{x^2+n^2}dx=\frac\pi n\cdot e^{-nt}$ . Then express your integral in terms of $I'_a(1)$ and $I'_b(1)$, since $\dfrac{d}{dt}\cos(tx)=-x\sin(tx)$, which, for $t=1$, becomes the numerator of our integrand.

Comment: Is differentiation under the integral sign the best way to go about that integral?

Comment: It's more a matter of personal taste or preference. It's neither simpler nor more difficult than other possible methods.

Comment: I was curious about this problem, so I started with your method. I may have made a silly calculation error, but I get that your $I_n(t)$ evaluates to $(\pi / n) \cdot \cosh(tn)$ using the residue theorem with an upper-half plane semicircle contour. How did you evaluate it?

Comment: You seem to have left out a $-\sinh(tn)$. Then we have $\cosh x-\sinh x=e^{-x}$.

Answer (score 2):

It may be good to try partial fractions.  The result it:

$$
\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{x\sin x}{(x^2+a^2)(x^2+b^2)} dx = 
\frac{\pi}{a^2-b^2}\left(\sinh(a)-\cosh(a)+\cosh(b)-\sinh(b) \right)
$$

Comment: I really don't understand why you got a downvote for a correct answer.  +1. Cheers.

Comment: $\cosh x-\sinh x=e^{-x}$.